# Como eliminar etiquetas y contenido de un string html con javascript

Tags: html, jquery, tags

Partamos del ejemplo de un código html que es un string y necesito eliminar una etiqueta y todo su contenido ya sea seleccionado por clase, id o nombre del tag ( div,script,em,ul,li, etc...) en concreto.
Me gustaria poder hacerlo con javascript o jquery. He probado con parseHTML y luego $(selector).remove() pero no funciona.

Mi codigo :

```
Var str = parseHTML($(#html).val());
var tags = $(#tag).val();
tags = tags.split(",");
        tags.forEach(t => {
            str = $(str).remove(t).end().html();
        });
        $(dest).val(str);
```

De que forma podría hacer esto siempre que al final resulte un string (de codigo html) con los elemntos eliminados

Comment: Hola J. Rafael Simarro, necesitas eliminar de un texto algo como **<div class="esta">**, osea, un parrafo que empiece con **<**, que contenga **class="esta"** (u otra cosa) y termine con **>**, entendí bien?.

Comment: No, de un texto que es código como html necesito poder elminar las etiquetas y su contendo puediendo seleccionarlas por nombre de etiqueta, por id o por clase. Por ejemplo eliminar(.esta) o eliminar(div) o eliminar(#id)